# How can I trim only (10) numbers in Python

Tags: python, hash, numbers, trim

```
hashCode = 0x39505b04f1c2e5c03ea3
```

I want to see only 10 characters, How ?

Comment: Please clarify what 10 numbers (or characters) you want.  [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/33183231) your question with the desired result and what you have tried yourself.

Comment: I wanted to print only the first 10 hashcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the first 10 characters:

```py
hashCode = '0x39505b04f1c2e5c03ea3'

print(hashCode[:10])
```

outputs:

```py
'0x39505b04'
```

If you want to instead see the last 10 characters:

```py
hashCode = '0x39505b04f1c2e5c03ea3'

print(hashCode[10:])
```

outputs:

```py
'f1c2e5c03ea3'
```